# Google EMM API and Android Management API

Tags: android, android-management-api

I am working on a custom EMM MDM solution. I did a lot of study about it and I came across these two APIs.

- Android Management API
- Google EMM API

Now I have few questions about these two APIs

1. I did about these two APIs individually but i don't why i find these
   APIs similar in functionality I just want to  know the main
   difference between of both these APIs or advantage and disadvantage
   of both APIs.
2. While provisioning a device with android management API, In DPC identifier method we write **afw#setup** when prompted to sign in which downloads Android Device Policy application but other MDMs for example In tiny MDM when user is going to enroll device, he writes **afw#tinymdm** when prompted to sign in which downloads their own application. Now what i need to do develop my own application and i write a code which downloads my app and user gets enrolled
3. What is actually NFC? In the documentation they wrote there is an admin device and u need to bump other device with admin device  to enroll device. I did same but nothing happens.
4. How can i share the files and contacts with all enrolled devices in android management API
5. How can i track the physical location of device in android management API

I eagerly wants the answer of these questions that I found nowhere yet.

Answer (score 4):

1. Google is no longer accepting new registrations for the [Play EMM API](https://developers.google.com/android/work/play/emm-api/register). It is mentioned on all EMM related webpages, this is done so that developers can start using the latest Android Management API.
2. `afw#setup` is the identifier for Android Management API, it will download the Android Device Policy and continue to setup. `afw#name` are identifiers of EMMs which were built on Play EMM APIs and have their own `DPC - Device Policy Controller` and now Google doesn't accept new identifiers.
3. `NFC` enrollment is a process to provision a device. [Link](https://developers.google.com/android/work/play/emm-api/prov-devices#nfc_method)

Would suggest to perform more research on `Android Management API` and also understand the options better.

Comment: I did a lot of research on android managment api...but now i want to have my own Device Policy Controller

Answer (score 0):

4. How can i share the files and contacts with all enrolled devices in android managment API

- There is currently no way to achieve this using Android Management API. However, you are free to use third-party applications to achieve this.

5. How can i track the physical location of device in android management API

- This has been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59845161/how-can-i-locate-a-device-which-has-been-enrolled-as-a-fully-managed-device/60221148#60221148).