# How to get the Location information of a device using android management API

Tags: android, kiosk-mode, android-management-api, android-enterprise, cosu

@Fred,
Using Android Management API how can we get the Location information of a device. Do we need to install any 3rd party application to get the location? How Location modes impact Location information?

Comment: Please don't ask multiple questions in one question, since only one answer can be marked as the answer to your question.

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no way to do this using Android Management API. You can use a policy to enable the location mode but you will need another 3rd party application to get the location of the device. You can check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60221148/12833618) on how to set the location policy.

For the location mode options, you can refer to this [link](https://developers.google.com/android/management/reference/rest/v1/enterprises.policies#locationmode). However, for devices running Android 9 and 10, setting the `locationmode` to any mode other than `OFF` or `LOCATION_DISABLED` will just turn on the location.